# Gentoo Live CD from Hard Drive: No Mountable Filesystems on root after modules loaded

Tags: linux, hard-disk, gentoo, livecd

I am attempting to install Gentoo on my PowerPC Mac. I have reached the point where I can boot the Live CD (I have no functional CD Drive, so it is from a spare Hard Drive), but after the kernel is loaded, I get a message `"No root found at /dev/hda`. It then gives me the options: `shell to get into a shell, q to skip, enter to try the same again`.

q to skip doesn't work, but it prints a nice warning `>> Skipping. This will likely cause a boot error.` Then it `can't find /newroot in /etc/SOMETHING` (I can't remember).

The shell won't really help me, if I try: dev/hda (the only thing I can find in /dev that looks like the second internal harddrive I am booting from), I only get the nice warning No mountable filesystems!.

Within the /boot/yaboot.conf file, the root is by default: `root=/dev/ram0`. Am I possibly missing a swap partition?

I changed the `device` within the yaboot.conf file to `ultra0:` as it is for that drive.

I used dd to copy the entire disk image to the drive, and it acknowledges itself to be a Live CD. The 40 GB hard drive even thinks it only has a 143.2MB capacity with 0 KB free. The only issue is: `/dev/cdrom` (which it seems to want to access) doesn't exist due to the hardware failure of my internal drive. The kernel will only even consider mounting valid drives within the /dev structure, so any advice on how to make the CD point to my drive?

Comment: Okay, does NOBODY know the answer to my question? A better one may be: If I `cp` something from my OSX /dev folder to the LiveCD /dev folder, does it point to the same device?
If I add the option `docache` to the boot, and set `root=ram0` as it is by default in yaboot.conf, could that work?

Comment: Sounds like something went wrong with the way you transferred the CD image to the hard drive. I'd recommend a utility like [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @Patrick, I'll give it a try! However, what I did was:
`sudo dd if=/Users/TMC/Desktop/Linux/install-powerpc-minimal-20120624.iso of=/dev/rdisk0`

Comment: @Patrick, __EDIT__: unetbootin only works for Intel Based computers, I have a PowerPC-based... A web-search for similar utilities only returns `dd` as an option, so I'll try again with that.
I think the greatest issue, however, is how /dev/cdrom is not valid, so I'll try solving this again by rebooting in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing a Debian installation disk to a USB flash drive using 'sudo dd if="~/Desktop/mini.img" of="/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m", then from a successful install of Debian I could chroot into a Gentoo tarball, and install that way. To reformat hard-drives, I booted into the "rescue" mode of the Debian install disk. Same went for fixing yaboot problems after I finished my install of Gentoo, by execting a shell inside the gentoo partition, I was able to fix yaboot without needing to boot the operating system.

I was at last successful, thank you all for the help.